# Specifying properties of parts in multipart rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to specify a multipart rectangle with different properties for different parts. I have the following code, but it is not working. In addition, for some reason the label of the first part is aligned with the base. I might be missing something, but I can't see anything wrong with the definition. Any suggestions for fixing both issues would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle split, draw,rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=4,text height=1cm,align=center] {\nodepart[fill=green!50]{text}Header \nodepart[fill=yellow,text width=3cm]{two} column values \nodepart[fill=green!50]{three}Header \nodepart[fill=yellow,text width=3cm]{four}Column values };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fill-color the parts using `rectangle split part fill={<list of colors>}`. Also, I think you wanted `minimum height` instead of `text height`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
  rectangle split, 
  draw,
  rectangle split horizontal, 
  rectangle split parts=4,
  minimum height=1cm,
  align=center,
  rectangle split part fill={green!50,yellow,green!50,yellow}
  ] 
  {Header%
    \nodepart[text width=3cm]{two} column values% 
    \nodepart{three}Header% 
    \nodepart[text width=3cm]{four}Column values
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you much (again...) It has been a long day and I am not even seeing the obvious things. I should take a break. Much appreciated.

Comment: How to change other options? I.e. if I want a dark fill color (frame color) for the top part; how would I make the text white in one part by default? Or maybe italic?